# pytorch LSTM does not overfit single sample

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I try to overfit a single time series. Meaning, I try to perform the training on a single `(X,Y)` pair over and over again. I do this to get an impression of the capabilities of the hyperparameters. But it does not converge. This is the loss plot showing the MSE per iteration after about 800 iterations:

[image]

I hoped that the error completely vanishes, but it gets stuck on the plateau, where it still is, as I write this.
The time series has the length `29600` and the RNN maps a single value onto another single value. It consists of an LSTM-Cell with `1` input,`200` hidden units and a fully connected Layer mapping onto a single value

My feeling tells me that the model may be not complex enough to fit the sample. But before I try to increase the complexity of the RNN, I have to be sure that my implementation of the training is correct. Maybe I did did not get the usage of autograd correctly. Since this is the first time, I ever tried to train a Neural network, I dont know, how long it should take.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable    
import numpy as np

# the class containing the LSTM
class Sequence(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hidden_state_len = 200
        super(Sequence, self).__init__()
        self.lstm1 = nn.LSTMCell(1, self.hidden_state_len)        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_state_len, 1)
        h_t = torch


    def forward(self, input):
        outputs = []
        h_t = torch.zeros(input.size(0), self.hidden_state_len, dtype=torch.double).cuda()
        c_t = torch.zeros(input.size(0), self.hidden_state_len, dtype=torch.double).cuda()

        for i, input_t in enumerate(input.chunk(input.size(1), dim=1)):            
            h_t, c_t = self.lstm1(input_t, (h_t, c_t))
            output = self.linear(h_t)
            outputs += [output]

        return torch.cat(outputs, dim=1)


x1 = torch.load("/floyd/input/wav/x1.pt").double().cuda()[0][7400:37000].reshape(1,-1)
y1 = torch.load("/floyd/input/wav/y1.pt").double().cuda()[0][7400:37000].reshape(1,-1)

seq = Sequence()
seq.double()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
seq = seq.cuda()
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
seq = seq.to(device)

optimizer = optim.Adam(seq.parameters())
starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
i = -1

# training for 4 hours on cloud GPU
while((datetime.datetime.now() - starttime).total_seconds() < 60*60*4) :
    i+=1
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    input = Variable(x1)
    target = Variable(y1)
    out = seq(input)    
    loss = criterion(out, target)
    loss.backward()    
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Just for testing, have you tried using `LSTM` and not `LSTMCell`. I don't see any special operations that would require the loop in your `forward` method.

Comment: Also, your training cycle certainly looks correct to me. You might want to use decaying learning rates if you insist on completely overfitting, but even then there is no guarantee of finding a global minimum. That's the whole point of having a non-convex optimization problem after all.